# What can cause a horn to go off by itself and not stop until you press it?

Tags: dodge, ram, horn

I have a 1998 Dodge Ram. For the past two days, the horn has gone off by itself around the same time (midday). It just stays in a long honk until I go out there and press the horn.

4 things that might be relevant..
Temperature has been getting really hot outside.
Took small dog to vet last week and it stood up on the horn, pressing it multiple times.
Battery is less than a year old, cheap, and has a weak charge now, which I believe may be caused by this horrible heat evaporating the battery acid. 
Changed the alternator to fusebox cable a few months ago but it may incorrect gauge.

I thought this horn issue might just be a wiring problem, but then why would pressing the horn make it stop? Could heat somehow cause this?

Comment: Is the temperature setting off the alarm???

Comment: The horn switch in the steering wheel hub is misbehaving, either because of age, or overuse (the dog!), or heat...or some combination. The real fix would be to remove the wheel or hub, disassemble, and bend or replace the spring medium which is supposed to keep the switch contacts open.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!